# How to ADD PEOPLE TO THIS PROJECT using python in Google Cloud?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am building a Pipeline template in Jupyter Notebook using [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-gcs.html) documentation from Snowflake and have reached the section where the doc states to **ADD PEOPLE TO THIS PROJECT**.
[image]

I've manually built the Pipeline and worked but I need to have it in a template that would be easy to deploy on other instances. I created the notification integration in snowflake and got my service account using `desc notification integration my_int`. I need to assign this service account the **Monitoring Viewer** role but can't find the library that allows me to do that.

**EDIT (Thanks @erhard):**

I realised I was using a different `serviceName` in my `discovery.build`.
Here is the working code:

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
gccreds = json.loads(open('gccreds.json', 'rt').read())
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gccreds)

crm_service = discovery.build(
    serviceName='cloudresourcemanager',
    version='v1',
    credentials=credentials)

gcp_pubsub_service_account = '<VALUE FROM SNOWFLAKE>'

policy = (
    crm_service.projects()
    .getIamPolicy(
        resource=project_id
    )
    .execute()
)
_ = [x for x in policy["bindings"] if f"serviceAccount:{gcp_pubsub_service_account}" in x["members"]] == []
if _:
    binding = {"role": "roles/monitoring.viewer", "members": [f"serviceAccount:{gcp_pubsub_service_account}"]}
    policy["bindings"].append(binding)
    print(f"Added '{gcp_pubsub_service_account}' with role 'roles/monitoring.viewer' to project")
else:
    print(f"'{gcp_pubsub_service_account}' with role 'roles/monitoring.viewer' to project already exists.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this page:

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-role

Comment: Thanks. I previously used this but couldn't see the `getIamPolicy` method. I later realised that the `service` I was using was **iam** and was supposed to be **cloudresourcemanager**